# Polar Equations (Complex)

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

So I'm trying to figure out what the angle $θ$ would equal at $x=-2$ for the polar equation $r=θ+sin(2θ)$.

All I know is that $θ$ has a domain of $0\leθ\le \pi$ and $y < 1$ (pretty sure).

I think I either have to convert the equation into Cartesian form (but I can't figure out how to do that) or find the argument θ=arctan(y/x) with an unknown y, which I also can't figure out how to do...

I also know that $ x = r cos (\theta)$ and $x = -2$ into polar form is $x = 2 cis (\pi)$

Comment: You have that $x=r\cos \theta = \theta \cos \theta +\sin (2\theta)\cos \theta =-2$.

Comment: @OliverJones but how would I solve for $\theta$ without using numerical methods?

Comment: Are you should you've copied the question correctly? The equation looks a little tough.

Comment: If it's correct, you will need to use a calculator.